# Replacing string on a file that are checked in list view C#

Tags: c#, file, listview, checkbox

I am trying to create a program that will replace a string inside .txt file.
heres the trick. I am replacing the string in the file if they are checked,
but when I do an alternate check its still replacing the other.

```
    private void BatchReplace()
    {
        string sourceFolder = FilePath.Text;
        string searchWord = Searchbar.Text;

        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

        List<string> allFiles = new List<string>();
        AddFileNamesToList(sourceFolder, allFiles);
        if (listView1.CheckedItems.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (String file in allFiles)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x <= listView1.CheckedItems.Count - 1; x++)
                {
                    if (file.Contains(listView1.CheckedItems[x].Text))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("File contains: " + listView1.CheckedItems[x].Text);
                        try
                        {
                            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to replace \"" + Searchbar.Text + "\" with \"" + Replacebar.Text + "\"?", "WARNING!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                            {
                                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file);
                                string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                                reader.Close();

                                content = Regex.Replace(content, Searchbar.Text, Replacebar.Text);
                                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file);
                                writer.Write(content); writer.Close();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            }
                        }
                        catch
                        { 
                        } 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Check the files you want to rename");
        }
    }
   public static void AddFileNamesToList(string sourceDir, List<string> allFiles)
    {

        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir);

        try
        {
            foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
            {
                allFiles.Add(fileName);
            }

            //Recursion    
            string[] subdirectoryEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(sourceDir);
            foreach (string item in subdirectoryEntries)
            {
                // Avoid "reparse points"
                if ((File.GetAttributes(item) & FileAttributes.ReparsePoint) != FileAttributes.ReparsePoint)
                {
                    AddFileNamesToList(item, allFiles);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by `but when I do an alternate check its still replacing the other`?

Comment: example i have this on listview,
  x  123.txt
      456.txt
   x  789.txt
      234.txt
then if i have checked 123 and 789. it still replacing the string in 234 file

Comment: Surely that's because you get a match at the condition `file.Contains(listView1.CheckedItems[x].Text)`? I think a much simpler way to do this would be to store your files in a dictionary and then loop once through the checked items and retrieve the relevant files from the dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still confused about what you are trying to do, but to simplify things, why don't you, when you populate the `ListView` with the files in the directory, add the file path (or a file object) to the tag property of the `ListViewitem`?

That way, when you loop through the checked items, you can just retrieve the file directly instead of having to loop through two Lists at once.

Something like:

```
    private void BatchReplace()
    {
        string sourceFolder = FilePath.Text;
        string searchWord = Searchbar.Text;

        AddFileNamesToList(sourceFolder);
        if (listView1.CheckedItems.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Check the files you want to rename");
            return;
        }


                for (int x = 0; x < listView1.CheckedItems.Count; x++)
                {
                    var file = listView1.CheckedItems[x].Tag.ToString()
                        try
                        {
                            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to replace \"" + Searchbar.Text + "\" with \"" + Replacebar.Text + "\"?", "WARNING!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                            {
                                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file);
                                string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                                reader.Close();

                                content = Regex.Replace(content, SearchWord, Replacebar.Text);
                                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file);
                                writer.Write(content); 
                                writer.Close();
                            }
                        }
                        catch
                        { 
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }
```

Sorry for the indenting and also if this doesn't work straight as is, I haven't tested this.